# Tomcat 9 SSL/TLS -Failed to initialize component error

Tags: java, ssl, java-8, tomcat9, protocol-handler

I have Tomcat 9.0.12 and Java JDK/JRE 1.8.0_191. I'm trying to configure SSL/TLS. I've changed my server.xml file like this:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="443" />

<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
               keystoreFile="C:\my_certificate.pfx"
               keystorePass="my_password" keystoreType="PKCS12" />
```

My certificate file is *.pfx format. I run tomcat server via command line with startup.bat command. But i got an error like this (in my catalina.log):

```
...
05-Nov-2018 16:33:57.080 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
05-Nov-2018 16:33:57.190 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
05-Nov-2018 16:33:57.205 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol-443]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler instantiation failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:533)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:852)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:656)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:491)
...
```

when i try to connect http://localhost:443 i get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED which i added to below.

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED:

[image: Connection refused error screenshot]

Comment: Try different port as 4444 or 8443

Comment: I tried but nothings changed, i got same output.

Answer (score 10):

In **Tomcat 9.0.x** get rid of the below exceptions by updating the **protocol** attribute value in the **Connector** element of ***server.xml*** file.

**Exceptions:**

```
27-Mar-2020 08:06:45.726 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol-auto-null]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler instantiation failed

27-Mar-2020 08:06:44.929 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.<init> Protocol handler instantiation failed
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol
```

**Exception Syntax:**

```
<Connector port="9443" 
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
    maxThreads="200" 
    SSLEnabled="true" 
    scheme="https" 
    secure="true"
    clientAuth="want" 
    sslProtocol="TLS" 
    connectionTimeout="20000" 
    keystoreFile="D:\\MYAPP\\DINESH_LOMTE\\dlomte_keystore.jks" 
    keystorePass="cardinal" 
    keystoreType="JKS"
    truststoreFile="D:\\MYAPP\\DINESH_LOMTE\\dlomte_truststore.jks" 
    truststorePass="cardinal" 
    truststoreType="JKS"
/>
```

In the above **Connector** element syntax update the **protocol** attribute value

From

```
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
```

To

```
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
```

**Note:** In order to use an explicit protocol rather than rely on the auto-switching mechanism one of the below values may be used, choose as per your requirement

```
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - non blocking Java NIO connector
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol - non blocking Java NIO2 connector
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol - the APR/native connector.
```

Comment: Thanks, you highlight the correct configuration: adding the official page which goes over the topic https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

Answer (score 1):

For tomcat9 change the protocol to HTTP1.1 for 8443 connector.

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. 
It starts to initialize a non-io-blocking connector

```
05-Nov-2018 16:33:57.080 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

But your config suggests using io blocking connector

```
Http11Protocol
```

So maybe you'd try using other connector instead. In my case changing `Http11Protocol` to `Http11NioProtocol` helped to fix this error.